# How to prevent all Android apps from switching phone orientation (landscape/portrait) based on gyroscope on Android?

Tags: screen, orientation

I am using Android 11 (LineageOS 18.1), and I'd like to prevent Android from accidentally switching to portrait mode, like when I rotate the direction of gravity field. Camera app seem to be resetting phone orientation against all preferences.

I tried:

1. setting rotation settings in android settings

   - *worked, but restarting camera overrides this setting, reverting back to portrait*
2. to disable sensors in developer mode

   - *worked, but doesn't preserve state between system reboots*
3. app "Rotation Lock + Landscape" from F-Droid

   - *worked, but restarting camera overrides this app, reverting back to portrait*

After all (1.,2.,3.) together, the mode came back to portrait after restart, and I started getting error "`open camera error id = 0`" upon trying to open camera, which only disappeared after factory reset... :/

So, none of that fully worked.

I want to permanently prevent all apps from switching screen orientation based on gyro, and the phone not resetting orientation during startup: set the orientation "in stone" (permanently, and so that I could only manually switch between it).

Comment: This seem to be a general problem of Android that even if rotation lock is active on system level, apps can change the orientation based on rotation sensor and afterwards the orientation stays.